# how do i know which keyframe has actionscript in it. does cs4 have an option that shows me all scripts?

Tags: flash

how do i know which keyframe has actionscript in it. does cs4 have an option that shows me all scripts ? i just started learning flash and the way adobe has set it for users to put their actionscript onto keyframes is really dumb.

Comment: You just started learning and you call them dump? May be you should think again.

Answer (score 2):

When a keyframe has actionscript in it you'll see a little 'a' above it.

Answer (score 1):

In as3 projects most of code is in Classes files. If code is put into keyframes it can be only simple code in MC or complex in first frame of main timeline. Code you can find with Movie Explorer window.